# How can an object reference work as a boolean expression?

Tags: c++

I'm reading file by file stream in the C++ Standard Library:

```
std::ifstream infile(path.c_str());
if (!infile.is_open())
{
    return -1;
}
std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

This works. What impressed me is that `std::getline` actually returns an `std::ifstream&`; how can a reference to object work as a boolean expression? Second, if I write it this way:

```
while (NULL != std::getline(infile, line))
```

this also works. I don't get it why a reference here works like a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the object reference: `std::ifstream` supports conversion to `bool` (it used to be `void*` before C++11), as you can see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool.

It returns `true` (a non `null` pointer before C++11) unless the stream is in error or at EOF.

Comment: Implicitly converted, copy that, thanks. So it's better to put it like this way while (NULL != (void*)std::getline(infile, line)), and c++11 changed that to (bool)std::getline.

Answer (score 4):

`std::ifstream` is [convertible to boolean](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/).  Specifically, it's true if the stream is `good`, and false if the stream is `bad` or `fail`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::ifstream` defines `void *` [conversion operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/). So you can compare the reference with a pointer and as a boolean condition.

Quoting about the return value of this conversion operator from cplusplus.com

> **Return Value**: A null pointer if at least one of failbit or badbit is set. Some other
>   value otherwise